# npm optimist don't passing some arguments,Windows

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
const argv = require('optimist').argv;
console.log(argv.worker, argv.m);
```

output

```
node index.js -worker test -m 5
undefined 5
```

Alos getting undefined for parameters containing more than 1 letter. I tried in Linux system, there it works(forget this),Is there any solution?

node v8.9.4,
optimist v0.6.1
cmder/cmd

Answer (score 0):

According to [optimist's docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimist#with-optimist-the-options-are-just-a-hash-no-optstrings-attached), long options should be passed with double dashes (as is the UNIX way).

Have you tried

```
node index.js --worker test -m 5
```

?